# How to use nav.popTo() (ionic 2)?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm using NavController. To go back I can use nav.pop(), but how to use nav.popTo() if I need go to the other page (not last)?

```
constructor(nav: NavController) {
this.nav = nav;

this.nav.push(MyNextPage);
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is the code to go up two levels, that is to the parent page of the previous page.

```
this.navCtrl.popTo(this.navCtrl.getByIndex(this.navCtrl.length()-3));
```

Pop to the root page.

```
this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
```

Comment: I cannot find popTo in docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: It's gone dark on their documentation. lmao! :(

Answer (score 4):

you mast get index `this.navCtrl.getByIndex(int i)` and set it inside the `popTo()`, see the code bellow:

```
this.navCtrl.popTo( this.navCtrl.getByIndex(1));
```

with this example, you can pop two pages

Comment: Thankyou.. this.navCtrl.getByIndex(int i) is working in Ionic 3. Previously in Ionic 2 I was using  this.navCtrl.popTo(0) and it stopped working when I upgraded to Ionic 3.

Answer (score 2):

If you're lazy loading you'll need something like this:

```
let targetView = this._navCtrl.getViews().filter(view=> view.id == 'MyAwesomePage')
targetView.length ? this._navCtrl.popTo(targetView[0]) : this._navCtrl.pop()
```

Note that you may handle the off case with something other than just a pop()

If you want more control on which instance of the view you want to go to, you can try something like this:

```
let index: number;
let views: any[] = this._navCtrl.getViews()
let found: boolean = views.some((view, i) =>{
  index = i
  return (view.id == 'MyAwesomePage')
})
found ? this.navCtrl.popTo(views[index]) : this._navCtrl.pop()
```

You may getViews().reverse().filter() or views.reverse().some() to get last occurrences.

This is using Ionic 3 and Array.some() from ES5

Answer (score 0):

`nav.popTo()` is for stepping back several levels in your page hierarchy.

For example, if your page hierarchy is `login -> welcome -> article1 -> detail1` you might use something like:

```
constructor(nav: NavController) {
this.nav = nav;

this.nav.popTo(MyWelcomePage);
```

To go back to your welcome page. See docs for further nav methods and details: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/#popTo

Comment: Hi can you show how to retrive that `MyWelcomePage` view? I have no idea how to retrieve the view that I want to go to.

Comment: Your MyWelcomePage needs to be ViewController type which was passed into your detail1-page via NavParams all the way from the welcome-page

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Ionic's `nav.setRoot(@component)`?

Taking the above example, you could easily do

`nav.push(welcome) -> nav.push(article1) -> nav.push(detail1)`

and to go back to the welcome page, just simply `nav.setRoot(welcomePage)`

**Edit:** I think this resets the stack.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Issue with ionic 2 popTo(). The Ionic Team is expected to fix it.

See Links below:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/viewcontroller-and-popto-ionic-2/53704

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6513

Answer (score 0):

It's late but for someone who want it, see https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/navigation/nav-controller.ts link.

```
abstract popTo(page: Page | string | ViewController, opts?: NavOptions, done?: TransitionDoneFn): Promise<any>;
```

So you can use popTo('pagename' or PageName or index) and with options too.