# Difference between pop and popTo method Ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

What is the difference between **pop** and **popTo** method of NavController and in which scenarios we should use which one?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947496/how-to-use-nav-popto-ionic-2

Answer (score 0):

`nav.popTo()` is for stepping back several levels in your page hierarchy.

For example, if your page hierarchy is `login -> welcome -> article1 -> detail1` you might use something like:

```
constructor(nav: NavController) {
  this.nav = nav;
  this.nav.popTo(MyWelcomePage);
}
```

To go back to your welcome page. See docs for further nav methods and details: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/#popTo

**credits: [Wulf Solter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1265447/wulf-solter) @ [How to use nav.popTo() (ionic 2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947496/how-to-use-nav-popto-ionic-2) <-- not an accepted answer so can't mark as duplicate**

So basically `popTo()` will pop to a specific component while `pop()` will just pop the last pushed component on the stack (go back to previous page)