# Ionic : NavControlller.setRoot redirect me back to my page

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, paypal

I have a problem on my ionic application : when I try to navigate back to my HomePage after doing a PayPal payment I get directly redirected back to my page.

This only occurs when the app is deployed on my iOS device and the weird part is that if I don't proceed to any PayPal payment the navigation work perfectly.

Here some part of my code :

html :

```
[...]
<div id="page7" [hidden]="hidePage7">
  <h1>Order summary</h1>
  [...]
  <button class="bigButton" (click)="validatePage7()">VALIDER</button>
</div>

<div id="payment" [hidden]="hidePayment">
  <div class="upperPart">
    <h1>Paiement</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="paypal-button"></div>
</div>

<div id="page9" [hidden]="hidePage9">
  <div class="upperPart">
    <h1>Paiement</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="midPart">
    <h3>{{endMessage}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomPart">
    <button class="bigButton" (click)="goToHome()">ACCUEIL</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

typescript :

```
validatePage7(){

  this.bookingService.create(this.booking).subscribe((response) => {
    this.hidePage7 = true;
    this.hidePayment = false;

    paypal.Button.render({
      env: 'sandbox',

      payment: (data, actions) => {  
        return actions.request.post(Api.API_URL + '/payment/create-payment', {
          bookingId: response.id
        })
          .then(function (res) {
            return res.id;
          });
      },
      onAuthorize: (data, actions) => {
        return actions.request.post(Api.API_URL + '/payment/execute-payment', {
          paymentID: data.paymentID,
          payerID: data.payerID
        })
          .then((res) => {
            this.endMessage = "Commande réalisée avec succès !";
            this.hidePayment = true;
            this.hidePage9 = false;
          });
      }
    }, '#paypal-button');
  });
}

goToHome(){
  this.navController.setRoot(MainPage);
}
```

Comment: Which version of Ionic are you using? Also, are you trying to set the MainPage as the root page or are you just simply trying to pop back to the MainPage after the PayPal transaction is done?

Comment: Ionic 4.1.2 and I am trying to pop back to the MainPage. I've tried to do "popToRoot" but same result.

Comment: You may need to Make sure your RootPage is correctly set up, but you can use popTo and pick the page name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947496/how-to-use-nav-popto-ionic-2

Comment: I tried but it doesn't change : the thing is that i'm directed to the right page but just after (less than 1sec) back to my payment page

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this: `this.navController.popTo(this.navCtrl.getByIndex(0));//pops to menu page`

If the Menu Page is your root page you can use that function, if not you can change the index number and it will pop in the order of your page stack.

Edit: Alternative solution as stated in the comments would be to create a success page using .push(); and once navigated there allow user to pop back to MainPage.

Comment: The thing is that i'm directed to the right page but just after (less than 1sec) back to my payment page

Comment: Did you remove the .setRoot(); from the typescript file?

Comment: Yes, i tried to replace it with popToRoot() or with popTo(this.navCtrl.getByIndex(0)) but it's the same. I see the homePage for 1sec and i'm directly sended back to my payment page (sorry for the response time)

Comment: So something in your typescript file is causing the page to push back to the payment page. In your app.component.ts, does your root page variable say rootPage:any = MainPage;

Comment: Yes I have this. Why ?

Comment: I'm checking to see why your page is reloading the Payment page. Have you tried commenting out the paypal code to see if the button would navigate to the MainPage. Perhaps could be related to the paypal code in the typescript file?

Comment: Yes, i've tried commenting the whole PayPal code. And it work so I think it's related to it but I can't get rid of the PayPal payment ...

Comment: I've tried to replace the "popToRoot()" by a push and it works. But I really want to use pop and not push because it causes an other bug when the <div id="paypal-button"></div> is duplicated with a push

Comment: Well keep in mind that the pages stack from the root page so you would only want to push if you're adding a page to the stack after the Payment Page. So the only way I can think of using push would be to create a success page that pops back to MainPage, but other than that pop is what you need to use.

Comment: SOLUTION : As, the .push() worked i've done as you said : I've created a success page, pushed to it and then made a .popToRoot() button on the success page. (Still don't understand why it didn't worked from the payment page but anyway, it work now). Thanks @Stephen Romero

Comment: Awesome! glad to hear you got it working! Honestly there may have been something withinthe paypal component causing the issue, but now your app will look a little cleaner with the success page.